# What adjustments when doubling a cheesecake recipe?

Tags: cheesecake

My cheesecake recipe calls for a 9 in pie dish. I want to double the recipe and bake in a single, glass 9.5 in pie dish. I make it about every year for Christmas, but last year I made a pumpkin cheesecake in a 9 in pan, and it called for 32oz of cream cheese. It was awesomely thick! I was just wanting a thicker cheesecake. The recipe states to bake at 325 F for 35 minutes. How should I adjust?

The original recipe is as follows:

- 1 c crushed ginger snaps
- 3 Tbsp melted butter
- 1/2 c sugar
- 2 Tbsp sugar
- 16 oz cream cheese
- 2 tsp vanilla
- 1/2 c sour cream
- 2 eggs
- 1 c apple pie filling
- 1/2 c chopped walnuts
- 1/2 c toffee pieces

Bake at 325 F for 35 minutes

Comment: Can you post the cheesecake recipe? It doesn't seem like a 9.5inch pie dish will be large enough to accommodate your doubled recipe, if the base recipe requires a 9inch dish. Also, are you concerned about preventing cracking on the top? This will be harder to prevent for larger cheesecakes.

Comment: Geometry suggests that you'd need a 12 to 13 inch pie plate for double a 9-inch recipe, unless your 9.5 inch pie plate is nearly twice as deep as your 9 inch pie plate, or the recipe only fills the 9 inch plate halfway.

Comment: I make it about every year for Christmas, but last year I made a pumpkin cheesecake in a 9 in pan, and it called for 32oz of cream cheese. It was awesomely thick! Lol. Was just wanting a thicker cheesecake. The original recipe is as follows:
1 c crushed ginger snaps
3 Tbsp melted butter
1/2 c sugar
2 Tbsp sugar
16 oz cream cheese
2 tsp vanilla
1/2 c sour cream
2 eggs
1 c apple pie filling
1/2 c chopped walnuts
1/2 c toffee pieces 

Bake at 325 F for 35 minutes

Comment: NMJD did you get my recipe? :)

Comment: It's rather hard to read recipes posted as comments (since you can't format them), and also details tend to get lost in long comment threads. So, instead, please [edit] your question to include the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I was mislead by your "doubling" subject line ... which lead me to think of doubling an entire recipe.

Here's what I would do:

```
1 c crushed ginger snaps -- *no change*
3 Tbsp melted butter -- *no change*
Sugar 3/4 c.
16 oz cream cheese  -- *double*
2 tsp vanilla -- *double*
1/2 c sour cream  -- *2/3 cup* (almost double but not quite)
2 eggs  -- *3 eggs* (almost double but not quite)
1 c apple pie filling  -- *no change*
1/2 c chopped walnuts -- *no change*
1/2 c toffee piece -- *no change*
```

Then... pay special attention while baking. Bake to vicinity of original time, but monitor and change as needed because minor adjustment + or - time will be needed.

Also... keep good notes. That way you can repeat again, or come back here with Q's.